# Swap file returns to original size after reboot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, swapfile

I am trying to increase swapfile size on my raspberry pi 3.
I'm following this guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-change-swap-size-on-ubuntu-14-04) on DigitalOcean.

After successfully increasing the file and setting it up using mkswap and swpon commands everything works fine. I even tried filling my ram with random data to see if it is going to use the new swap space and it works perfectly.

However after I reboot my raspberry, swap file returns to the previous (default) size of 100MB.
Is there any way to make this change permanent?

I'm running Raspberry pi 3 on Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

Modifying /etc/dphys-swapfile solves all problems.

I just changed `CONF_SWAPSIZE=100` to `CONF_SWAPSIZE=2000`

dphys-swapfile is responsible for setting up, mounting/unmounting and deleting swap files.

In the configuration file you can also specify the location of the swap file as well as few other parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have got to the point where `swapon -s` returns

```
# sudo swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        4194300    0          -1
```

Now to make this change permanent you need to add a record about your new swapfile in `fstab`.

You need to add the following line:

```
/swapfile       none       swap         sw        0      0
```

The meaning of the fstab fields is as follows:

```
#1.source   2.mountpoint  3.fstype  4.options   5.freq  6.order
```

Comment: I entered the line 
/var/swap       none            swap    sw                0       0
However after reboot it disappears and swapfile returns to original size.